# How to scale y-axis to intuitively detect small differences in data

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, scale

I have a data set from a literature survey, where we looked at effects of pH to certain parameters (`Metrics`) in a group of animals. Because experiments are done on different time scales, I divided the [response ratio](http://www.jstor.org/stable/177062) by time.

This leads to very small differences around 1 (less than 1, there is a negative effect, greater than 1 a positive effect), which are still interesting and important (because the real values are divided by time). The problem is that some of the values are either very low or very high and the differences close to 1 are not visible.

[image]

Since values are close to 1, log transformation of y-axis scale does not help. **How can I transform the y-axis scale in `ggplot2` so that differences close to 1 are visible and yet intuitive?** (that the reader can detect differences without thinking too much; I could standardize the values to minimum value, multiply by 10000 and take a log10 scale, but this would not lead to understandable differences.)

```
df <- structure(list(Study = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3), pH_control = c(8.06, 
8.06, 8.01, 8.01, 7.99), pH_treatment = c(7.86, 7.75, 7.8, 7.8, 
7.45), time = c(120, 120, 60, 150, 140), Metrics = structure(c(3L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("Growth", "Metabolism", "Survival"
), class = "factor"), RR_per_time_unit = c(0.9998, 1.001, 1.002, 
0.98, 0.9), CI.max = c(1, 1.003, 1.00003, 0.9999, 0.92), CI.min = c(0.9996, 
0.9999, 1.004, 0.9789, 0.89), pH_diff = c(0.2, 0.31, 0.21, 0.21, 
0.54)), .Names = c("Study", "pH_control", "pH_treatment", "time", 
"Metrics", "RR_per_time_unit", "CI.max", "CI.min", "pH_diff"), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = "data.frame")

df$pH_diff <- df$pH_control - df$pH_treatment

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(y = RR_per_time_unit, x = pH_diff, ymin = CI.min, ymax = CI.max)) + 
geom_pointrange(aes(color = Metrics)) + geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 1)) + coord_trans(y = "log10")
```

Comment: This issue here is not a technical one involving ggplot. You'll need to completely re-think your approach to visualizing this data. Either split the data into separate panels with different y axis limits, or fundamentally re-think the quantities you're graphing.

Comment: @joran There's no reason this wouldn't be solvable with ggplot by using a different y axis.

Comment: So a difference from the mean of 0.01 is nearly as significant as a difference of 0.1? If that's the case, you should definitely subtract the response ratio from 1 and use a log scale.

Comment: @TimN I don't see how, given that the OP has ruled out log transforms. My read on the question is that they are looking for something essentially impossible: visualize quantities on radically different scales, but on the same scale.

Comment: @joran I think that OP ruled out plotting against `log(y)`, but not other functions of y.

Comment: @TimN Possibly, but I suspect that would involve a fairly non-standard transformation that would be even harder to interpret. I'd be happy to be proven wrong, though.

Comment: Here's a shot: if you know what large numbers are not of interest, just get rid of them:  `foo[foo>2]<-NA` and then plot foo on a linear scale. If you must view all values, then a nonlinear transform of your choice is what's left.  Try `foo<-foo/exp(foo)` (that's partly a joke)

Comment: Thank you for your discussion. So I understand that there is not a scale that would be intuitive and would work for these kind of data (apart from x/exp(x) etc, which may not be that intuitive). I guess I could break the data into panels (`facet_wrap`) and use different `lim`in those. I also like the idea of subtracting from 1 (did it vice versa, but the you can't take the log).